# VBA message box with a list of failed checks

Tags: vba, list, msgbox

how do i create a message box that shows all of the mandatory fields that have not been filled in.

I am using a table that has an auto filter on it ("Table11") to show only the checks that have failed.

I want to translate these into a message box that show when a sales agent tries to create the contract.

Table layout below:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: To be honest i haven't tried anything as i don't know where to start, the best i could think of was `MsgBox " Please complete the following mandatory fields:" & vbNewLine & "Customer Name"` but this doesn't cycle through the list and add each item until it finds a blank cell then stops

Comment: Start with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx).  You could solve this by combining a [for...next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx) with a [MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251821.aspx).

Comment: I wasn't going to answer this as you showed no existing effort but your comments shows some thought. For best results always give it a shot and explain your issue and how you would like help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sample goes through `Table11` and creates a list of all those with marked with 'Check', Then displays a message if there were items.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim LngCounter  As Long
Dim Tbl         As Excel.Range
Dim StrMsg      As String

Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table11")
    For LngCounter = 2 To Tbl.Rows.Count
        If Trim(UCase(Tbl.Cells(LngCounter, 2))) = "CHECK" Then
            StrMsg = StrMsg & Tbl.Cells(LngCounter, 1) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next
Set Tbl = Nothing

If StrMsg <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following items need attention before continuing: - " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & StrMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Data Validation"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes CHECK means there's a problem

```
Sub ErrorMessage()
Dim strErrMsg As String
Dim cell As Range
If Application.CountIf(-yourfilteredrangehere-), "CHECK") = 0 Then Exit Sub
'no problems to output
For Each cell In Range(-yourfilteredrangehere-)
    'next line assumes checkitem in previous column, change if not
    If cell = "check" Then strErrMsg = strErrMsg & "Please check " & cell.Offset(0, -1) & vbCrLf
Next cell
MsgBox strErrMsg
End Sub
```